# SCSS complex/nested map

Tags: sass

I want to generate some CSS code out of an nested map but i can access the arguments and values. I've posted the map here. I want to have different classes. They should look like this.

```css
.is-fluid {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 border-radius: 0;
}
```

etc....

I tried different things but can't get it to run.
Is this even possible? And how?

```
$images: (
    styles: (
        fluid: (
            'width': 100%,
            'height': auto,
            'border-radius': 0
        ),
        rounded: (
            'width': auto,
            'height': auto,
            'border-radius': .5rem
        ),
        circled: (
            'width': auto,
            'height': auto,
            'border-radius': 50%
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

[Sass maps](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps).

```
$images: (
    styles: (
        fluid: (
            'width': 100%,
            'height': auto,
            'border-radius': 0
        ),
        rounded: (
            'width': auto,
            'height': auto,
            'border-radius': .5rem
        ),
        circled: (
            'width': auto,
            'height': auto,
            'border-radius': 50%
        )
    )
);

@each $style-name, $style-content in map-get($images, 'styles') {
  .is-#{$style-name} {
    @each $key, $value in $style-content {
        #{$key}: #{$value}; 
    }
  }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
.is-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.is-rounded {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.is-circled {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much!